# How to clear a directory before running Protractor tests

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, protractor

I have a `Protractor` test to validate that an excel file is correctly downloaded in the `Downloads` folder and then I am able to upload the same. Since I will be running the test multiple times, I need a way to clear my `Downloads` directory before I run the Protractor tests. That way any duplicate files from the previous runs are cleared. How can I do that? This is how my test to upload an excel file looks:

```
var fileToUpload = 'Test.xlsm';

it('Test Case: to Validate the Excel Upload', function() {

    var absolutePath = path.resolve('C:/Users/.../Downloads', fileToUpload);

    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath); 


    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to remove all files in the "Downloads" directory inside the `onPrepare()` function which you define inside your [Protractor configuration file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts).

Let's use the synchronous [`rmDir` function](https://gist.github.com/liangzan/807712) suggested here (feel free to use a different method):

```
var fs = require('fs');

function rmDir (dirPath) {
  try { var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath); }
  catch(e) { return; }
  if (files.length > 0)
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var filePath = dirPath + '/' + files[i];
      if (fs.statSync(filePath).isFile())
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
      else
        rmDir(filePath);
    }
  fs.rmdirSync(dirPath);
}; 

module.exports = {
  // ...

  onPrepare: function () {
    rmDir('C:/Users/.../Downloads');
  },
};
```

It is also probably a good idea to avoid specifying the path to the "Downloads" directory multiple times and in multiple places (see: [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) - see if you can have it inside a configuration file and reuse, or define as an *environment variable*.

Comment: I am also trying to do the same changes in my Config file, but when I run the test it fails saying : `export const config = {
^^^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and share your feedback

```
Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(
                new File(String.valueOf(dir)).listFiles())).forEach(File::delete);
```